# Laplace transform to Z-transform for filter design

Tags: laplace-transform, digital-filter, z-transform

I was given an answer to the following question I can't understand, that how is the Impulse Invariance transformation of
$$\frac{(s+a)}{(s+a+jb)(s+a-jb)}$$ is
$$\frac{(1-e^{-aT} cos(bT) z^{-1})}{(1-e^{(-a-jb)T} cos(bT) z^{-1})(1-e^{(-a+jb)T} cos(bT) z^{-1})}$$ ?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Suffice to say you can get help with homework, but you have to show your attempt and where you are having problems.  Also this appears to be pure algebra so you might want math stack exchange.

Comment: it's not my home work and also I've tried math stack, but can't get any answers.